# how to insert text at specific lines in vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to put cursor at specific lines that is:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

I know how to edit those three lines using `CTRL_V` and then `SHIFT_I`, but my question is how do i edit the first and the last line and leave out the second line that is:

```
test_AAA
BBB
test_CCC
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim doesn't have a built-in "multiple cursors" feature. If you want to do it the vanilla way, you can use `:help .`:

```
" cursor is on first A
> AAA
  BBB
  CCC

" do itest_<Esc>
> test_AAA
  BBB
  CCC

" move the cursor to CCC
  test_AAA
  BBB
> CCC

" press .
  test_AAA
  BBB
> test_CCC
```

or the almighty `:help :global`, which is the de-facto way to operate on non-contiguous line:

```
:g/^AA|^CC/s/^/test_
```

And there are many other ways.

Or you can ask your favourite engine to help you find the couple of plugins that replicate that feature: "vim multiple cursors".

Answer (score 0):

You could use a reverse global command:

```
:v/^BBB/norm Itest_
```

Explanation:

The normal global command uses "g" instead of "v" which inverts the search, so, for each line that does not start with BBB use the normal command "I" (insert)